# What is the correct interface for Slim's container?

Tags: php, interface, slim

I am trying to implement the `Allow Slim to instantiate the controller` portion described by https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html.  When doing so, I get the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to Michael\Test\HomeController::__construct() must
>   be an instance of Slim\ContainerInterface, instance of Slim\Container
>   given, called in
>   /var/www/slimtest/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php on line
>   93

Thinking it might have been namespace related, I also tried in the `\` namespace but got the same error.

Is the documentation on https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html incorrect and should HomeController's constructor argument declaration type be `Slim\Container`, or am I doing something wrong and `Slim\ContainerInterface` is correct?

```
<?php
namespace Michael\Test;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App();
$container = $app->getContainer();
//$container['view'] = function ($c) {};

//Question.  Do I need to use the fully qualified class name???
$app->get('/', \Michael\Test\HomeController::class . ':home');
//$app->get('/', '\Michael\Test\HomeController:home');

$app->run();
```

Home Controller

```
namespace Michael\Test;
class HomeController
{
    protected $container;

    // constructor receives container instance
    public function __construct(\Slim\ContainerInterface $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function home($request, $response, $args) {
        // your code
        // to access items in the container... $this->container->get('');
        return $response;
    }

    public function contact($request, $response, $args) {
        // your code
        // to access items in the container... $this->container->get('');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\Slim\ContainerInterface` doesn't exist (see [here](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/tree/3.x/Slim)). Looking at the implementation of `\Slim\Container` the interface you need to use is `Interop\Container\ContainerInterface` or you can just use the Slim implementation `\Slim\Container` as type parameter.

Comment: Thank you.  Would you agree that the documentation is incorrect?

Comment: I wouldn't say that the documentation is incorrect, just unclear, you could change [this file(router.md)](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Website/blob/gh-pages/docs/v3/objects/router.md) to make it more clear and create a pull request to the slim website.

Comment: `Interop\Container\ContainerInterface` is actually just an alias to `Psr\Container\ContainerInterface`, so you can also use Psr's `ContainerInterface`.